# Integrating CMake and ndk-build external libraries into an Android Studio project

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I have two existing native libraries that I would like to integrate into an Android project. One has a working Android.mk file and the other has a working CMakeList.txt file. Is there a clean way to link both to Gradle?

Using CMake's ExternalProject[1] is the only idea I have at the moment.

[1] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: your idea of using ExternalProject was discussed here: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/268

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I arrived at was to add an additional Gradle module to build the ndk-build project. In Gradle terms the project would become a multi-project/multi-module build and is discussed further here [1]. I was also able to express the dependency in Gradle and the project built without issue.

My initial thought of using CMake's ExternalBuild failed under Gradle, but would build fine when invoking CMake from the command line. This probably had something to do with my lack of knowledge in Gradle and CMake.

[1] https://speakerdeck.com/bmuschko/state-of-the-art-gradle-multi-module-builds

Comment: Can you please share an example for this? I want to accomplish the same thing inside my project.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I held on to this. One of the libraries I was using was libusb and I hit a wall in Android with getting permissions to access the USB device from a native lib. I ended up using Android's USB API, and that eliminated the need for the native lib.

Answer (score 0):

I might have what you need. There is an all `c++` sample that involves **no JAVA UI** which is actually a big thing because now your `main` (entry point) is in a `c++` file - you can do OOP and depend on 3rd party libraries without much hassle.

Check out my repo: https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line